# Checking equivalence of two expression

Tags: algebra

[image: s]

whenever I tried to check this I got "False" for ln[2] and I do not know how to overcome this situation. Actually these two expressions are the elements of a matrix and I can not check either both are same or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` checks for structural sameness, not mathematical equivalence.

You could force both sides to have same structure as follows

```
Sin[t a2]*(I Cos[t a1] - w Sin[t a1]/a1) === Sin[t a2]*(I Cos[t a1] - w Sin[t a1]/a1)
```

(* True *)

```
 Expand[Sin[t a2]*(I Cos[t a1] - w Sin[t a1]/a1)] === 
            Expand[-Sin[t a2]* (-I Cos[t a1] + w Sin[t a1]/a1)]
```

(* True *)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way is simplify `lhs - rhs` and see if you get zero

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eq = Sin[t a2]*(I Cos[t a1] - w Sin[t a1]/a1) == -Sin[t a2]* (-I Cos[t a1] + w Sin[t a1]/a1);
lhs = eq /. (lhs_) == (rhs_) :> lhs
rhs = eq /. (lhs_) == (rhs_) :> rhs
Simplify[lhs - rhs]

(* 0 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way is

```
Simplify[eq]
(*True*)
```